# La « bifurcation » des caténaires : antonymie, emplois analogues ?

Tags: usage, terminologie, transports, antonyme

> Presque toujours au nombre de deux par machine, les [pantographes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pantographe)
>   exercent un certain effort de bas en haut sur les fils de contact dont
>   ils suivent automatiquement les variations de hauteur. Un pantographe
>   se compose, essentiellement: −d'un bâti (...) fixé sur le toit de la
>   machine au moyen d'isolateurs; −de cadres en tubes d'acier (...)
>   articulés autour des axes (...); −d'une semelle (...) qui porte les
>   surfaces de contact avec la [caténaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cat%C3%A9naire).
>
> [ [Matér. roulant ch. de fer](https://books.google.com/books?id=cklGAAAAYAAJ&dq=mat%C3%A9riel%20roulant%20chemin%20de%20fer%20bailleul&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22pantographe%22), Bailleul, 1951, au TLFi à
>   [*pantographe*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pantographe) ]

On parle du mécanisme par lequel une locomotive est alimentée en électricité quand la semelle du pantographe entre en contact avec la caténaire qui elle est suspendue à l'aide des supports le long de la voie ferrée ; il s'agit de transport de courant par [caténaire](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8876961). La caténaire est un emprunt au [latin](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=catenarius) dans le sens de *(relatif à la) chaîne*. Généralement on peut imaginer que la direction que prend la caténaire ressemble à celle que prend la voie ferrée. Et donc on présente un exemple, possiblement d'un emploi [technique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18097177), avec la [*bifurcation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bifurcation) dans le sens de « [d]ivision en deux branches, en deux voies à la manière d'une fourche » (TLFi) (on a même la [*trifurcation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trifurcation), rare comme mot, et autres [trucs particuliers](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=10899354), emplois par métonymie avec la route, la rivière, la plomberie etc.) :

> Votre regard n'a pu la suivre qu'un instant [la locomotive] comme ...
>   ces signaux, ces caténaires, leurs poteaux et leurs bifurcations [...]
>
> [ [La Modification](https://books.google.com/books?id=UoU_AQAAIAAJ&dq=M.%20Butor%2C%20La%20Modification&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=bifurcations), M. Butor, 1957 ]

On y parle bien de la *bifurcation des caténaires*, phénomène sans doute particulièrement prononcé à l'approche de certaines gares.

---

- Quel est l'antonyme de la *bifurcation des caténaires* ?
- Est-ce le même terme qu'on utilise avec la voie ferrée ?
- Généralement, à l'extérieur du vocabulaire professionnel, emploie-t-on ces termes (*bifurcation*, son antonyme etc.) pour décrire un phénomène analogue (avec la route, l'eau, l'objet etc.) ?

Comment: In English, mostly for highways but also for railways, I use “splits” & “merges” (both as nouns) for *bifurcations* & *jonctions*, respectively, eg: “avoid THE 95/295 split/merge” (but it’s argued that “merge” as a noun is limited to source control/computer programming). Although I’ve seen “faire *un/e merge*” used in French in word processing/computer lingo to mean “a joining," I don’t think French has extended its use as a noun (or as a verb for that matter) to traffic. (cf: "merger" the noun in the business sense = *fusion* & "merge" as verb in the road sense = *se joindre* ?=? *jointure*)

Comment: @PapaPoule Thanks! _Deux routes se joignent_... I think it would be _rejoignent_; but couldn't that be just connecting and not necessarily the (symmetrical) fish tail becoming its body so to speak loll. Your sort of thinking echoes the last point of the question. Often we know less about waterways, have you given some thought about how what you said would apply to a river for instance; or to plumbing?

Comment: Your mention of a symmetrical fish re *se [re]joindre* got me wondering (at least in the case of railroads/their network of overhead power lines, where the same points/roads/lines are alternatingly shared by trains going in different directions) if “bifurcation” really has or needs to have  an antonym (or if perhaps it is its own antonym!?), for isn’t 1 [northbound] engineer’s bifurcation another [southbound] one’s jonction (& “bifurcation” & “jonction” share some synonyms [fourche/embranchement/carrfour/intersection] at CRNTL, supporting perhaps this philosophic, if not linguistic, view)?....

Comment: ... Regardless, for things like highways & rivers, whose merges and splits (for roads) are at two different places, I’d use “[point of] convergence” where rivers merge & “[point of] divergence” (& curiously enough, “[point of] bifurcation” in the English sense, which could also be support for the “bifurcation is its own antonym” view?) where they split.  For plumbing, I’d use “Tees” (for the letter ‘T’) or “Tee Branches” for where water under pressure divides to head for faucets  & “Wyes” (for the letter ‘Y’) or “Wye Branches” for where waste water combines to ‘head’ for the sewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

à première vue j'aurais dit convergence, mais une recherche dans cntrl ( http://www.cnrtl.fr/antonymie/bifurcation ) donne **jonction**.

> Gare de jonction.

Gare où s'effectue la jonction de deux ou plusieurs lignes ou réseaux de chemin de fer, et qui permet le transit ou le triage des rames de passage.

Il faut aussi noter, qu'une jonction est une bifurcation quand on va dans l'autre sens (sur rail comme sur route).